# how to get result of query in view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have use two query to get result on the view.
To get the  result of  resultq1  i use foreach but how can i get result of resultq2 in view.

For each row of resultq1 i get record "reccount" in resultq2.

//controller

```
     //Query 1
     $q = $this->db->select(array(
                'spf.id as id' ,
                'spf.name',
                "if(u.username != '',u.username,spf.added_by) as added_by ",
                'spf.added_on'
              ))->from('sp_forum spf')->join('sp_users u', 'spf.added_by = u.id', 'left')->where($where)->order_by('spf.id desc')->limit(10, $page * 10)->get();

            $resultq1= $q->result_array();
            $data['resultq1'] = $resultq1;

            $resultq2 = array();
             $i=0;
            foreach($resultq1 as $rec)
             {
                      //query 2
                 $id = $rec['id'];
                 $q1 = $this->db->select("count('id') as reccount ")->from('sp_forum_topic spft')->where('spft.forumid',$id)->get();
                 $resultq2[$i] =  $q1->row_object();
                 $i++; 
               }

$this->load->view('forumview', $data, true);
```

//view file

```
<table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="th"> Details</td>
        <td width="5%" class="th"> Answer</td>
        <td width="15%" class="th">Started by</td>
        <td  width="15%" class="th">Created on</td>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($resultq1 as $row):?>
       <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ;?></td>

         <td >---- </td> // here i want to use resultq2

         <td><?php echo $row['added_by'] ;?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['added_on'];?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
```

Array print in view for resultq2.
Resultq1 have 4 rows so that i get 4 value in resultq2.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [reccount] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [reccount] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [reccount] => 0 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [reccount] => 2 ) ) 0002
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `$resultq2` to the view as well.

In the controller, just before calling the view

```
$data['resultq2'] = $resultq2
```

You can now use `$resultq2` in your view.

PS - SQL queries should be in models, not controllers.

Comment: Xbonez:i also use this but problem is how can i get this in my view.see my view.

Answer (score 0):

Just Write '$data['resultq2'] = $resultq2' before loading the view,

```
$data['resultq2'] = $resultq2
$this->load->view('forumview', $data, true);
```

And you can retrieve it in the view by $result2 variable.

Just do `var_dump($result2);` in your view file, You will get the complete data of $result2 varaible.

And xbonez is right, do write your DB queries in the model, controller is only for login, and coordinating between (models, views, libraries, helper etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I optimized your second query a bit, but logic is pretty much the same.

```
$q = $this->db->select(array(
    'spf.id as id' ,
    'spf.name',
    "if(u.username != '',u.username,spf.added_by) as added_by ",
    'spf.added_on'
    ))->from('sp_forum spf')->join('sp_users u', 'spf.added_by = u.id', 'left')->where($where)->order_by('spf.id desc')->limit(10, $page * 10)->get();

    $resultq1= $q->result_array();
    $data['resultq1'] = $resultq1;
    $ids = array();
    foreach($resultq1 as $result)
        $ids[] = $result['id'];

     $resultq2 = $this->db->select("count('id') as reccount ")->from('sp_forum_topic spft')->where_in('spft.forumid',$ids)->get();

    foreach( $resultq2->result_array() as $res )
        $newArr[$res['forumid']] = $res;

    $data['resultq2'] = $newArr;
```

After resultq2 is indexed by original id, its easy to use id from resultq1 loop to show correct data

```
<table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="th"> Details</td>
        <td width="5%" class="th"> Answer</td>
        <td width="15%" class="th">Started by</td>
        <td  width="15%" class="th">Created on</td>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($resultq1 as $row):?>
       <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ;?></td>

         <td >
            <?php

                print_r( $resultq2[$row['id']]);

            ?>
        </td> // here i want to use resultq2

         <td><?php echo $row['added_by'] ;?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['added_on'];?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This should fix it.

#### Modify the controller - see comments also

```
<?php
//Query 1

  $q = $this->db->select(array(
  'spf.id as id',
  'spf.name',
  "if(u.username != '',u.username,spf.added_by) as added_by ",
  'spf.added_on'
  ))->from('sp_forum spf')->join('sp_users u', 'spf.added_by = u.id', 'left')->where($where)->order_by('spf.id desc')->limit(10, $page * 10)->get();

  $resultq1 = $q->result_array();
  $data['resultq1'] = $resultq1;   

$resultq2 = array();
foreach ($resultq1 as $rec) {
    //query 2
    //echo $id = $rec['id']; //Test and See if all IDs echo out correctly
    $data["id"] = $id; //Add this for the ID
    $q1 = $this->db->select("count('id') as reccount, spft.forumid")->from('sp_forum_topic spft')->where('spft.forumid', $id)->get();
    $resultq2[$id] = $q1->result(); //Change this line
    $data["resultq2"][$id] = $resultq2[$id]; //Add this line
}

//echo "<pre>";
//$export = var_export($data, true);// Test the returned value...
//echo "</pre>";
$this->load->view('forumview', $data, true);
?>
```

#### In Your view

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="th"> Details</td>
        <td width="5%" class="th"> Answer</td>
        <td width="15%" class="th">Started by</td>
        <td  width="15%" class="th">Created on</td>
    </tr>
    <?php //foreach ($resultq1 as $row):  ?>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php
                //$resultq2 is now array
                //print_r($resultq2); //Do this so you can see the depth of the array

                foreach ($resultq2 as $counts) {
                    foreach ($counts as $count) { //The second foreach might be necessary - please test
                        echo $count->reccount; //This should print out the count result
                        //echo "<br />";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['added_by']; ?></td>
            <td ><?php echo $row['added_on']; ?></td>
            <td >

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    exit;
    ?>
</table>
```

I haven't had time to test it but it should work. Let me know if you find any issues:

Comment: Can you do one thing for me: Give me what is returned is you run this:  `$resultq1= $q->result_array();  print_r($resultq1)` Since I don't have the db, I can test rigorously

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => new forum [added_by] => 16 [added_on] => 2012-08-04 21:55:12 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Third Forum [added_by] => Innovate [added_on] => 2012-08-04 21:55:12 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Second Forum [added_by] => robert [added_on] => 2013-02-18 02:44:38 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => First Forum [added_by] => joyson [added_on] => 2013-02-18 02:44:38 ) )

Comment: `$resultq1= $q->result_array(); print_r($resultq1)`. What you are giving me is for the second query. I need for the first query. That's where I think your problem is right now

Comment: Sorry, could you do a var_export so I could use the values. That would make me faster. thanks

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'name' => 'new forum', 'added_by' => 'jack', 'added_on' => '2012-08-04 21:55:12', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'name' => 'Third Forum', 'added_by' => 'Innovate', 'added_on' => '2012-08-04 21:55:12', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'name' => 'Second Forum', 'added_by' => 'robert', 'added_on' => '2013-02-18 02:44:38', ), 3 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'name' => 'First Forum', 'added_by' => 'joyson', 'added_on' => '2013-02-18 02:44:38', ), )

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to get my internet connection back. Lost it suddenly. I've update the answer and it works well from my end. Run it against your database and let's see if that does the job.